# Como associar valores Inteiros ou Float com Boleano em ELM via documento HTML?

Tags: algoritmo, elm

tudo bem ?
Eu me deparei com um problema simples. Escreva um algoritmo que receba um número e diga se ele é impar. A resposta tem que ser em boleanos. Se o número for ímpar  True, se for par False ! 
Até aí tudo bem, no terminal do elm (o qual tenho instalado, mas caso você não tenha já deixo esse terminal online: http://elmrepl.cuberoot.in/) eu consegui reproduzir a função da seguinte forma:
impar number = if (modBy 2 number) == 0 then False  else True
(o modBy ele da o resto é tipo o % em algumas linguagens)
Agora vem a questão ! Eu quero saber como fazer essa mesma função ser apresentada só que em código Html : https://ellie-app.com/new 
Mas o elm não reconhece a ligação entre o número Int e o Bool na hora de imprimir a função e acaba dando error. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Criei uma função auxiliar `toString()`, funcionou no https://ellie-app.com/new.

```
module Main exposing (main)

import Browser
import Html

toString : Bool -> String
toString bool = if bool then "True" else "False"

impar number = if (modBy 2 number) == 0 then False else True

main = Html.text (toString (impar 5))
```